# Chapel - Ranges defined using bounds of type 'range(int(64),bounded,false)' are not currently supported

Tags: chapel

The title "Ranges defined using bounds of type 'range(int(64),bounded,false)' are not currently supported" shows up as error when I try to compile this 5-point stencil benchmark code. What is causing this? I use chapel 1.8.2, and it does not show up when only compiling the procedures.

```
use Time;
use IO;

/* Use ./2dstencil --n=20000 --iterations=5 to run with different arguments. */
config const n: int = 10000;
config const iterations: int = 10;

const constants = [[0.0, 0.5, 0.0],
                   [0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
                   [0.0, 0.5, 0.0]];

proc relax(input: [1..n, 1..n] real)
{
    var output: [1..n, 1..n] real;

    /* Inner part */
    forall i in [2..n - 1] do
        forall j in [2..n - 1] do
            output[i, j] = + reduce (input[i - 1..i + 1, j - 1..j + 1] * constants);

    /* Boundary */
    output[1, 1..n] = input[1, 1..n];
    output[n, 1..n] = input[n, 1..n];
    output[1..n, 1] = input[1..n, 1];
    output[1..n, n] = input[1..n, n];

    return output;
}

proc stencil(input: [1..n, 1..n] real)
{
    var copy: [1..n, 1..n] real = input;

    for t in [1..iterations] do
        input = relax(input);

    return input;
}

var input: [1..n, 1..n] real = 1;
var watch: Timer;
watch.start();

input = stencil(input);
watch.stop();
stderr.writeln('Anti-optimisation number: ', + reduce input, '\n');

stdout.writeln(watch.elapsed(), '\n');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit subtle, but the cause of the problem is the following loops:

```
    forall i in [2..n - 1] do
        forall j in [2..n - 1] do
```

Specifically, I believe you're writing these with the intention to have i and j be integer variables looping from 2 through n-1.  In order to get that behavior, you would need to drop the square brackets from these expressions for the following reason:

The syntax `[expr-list]` in Chapel represents an array literal whose elements are the expressions between the square brackets.  E.g., `forall i in [1, 3, 5, 4, 6]` would loop over the integers represented by that array literal.  In your code, you're looping over a 1-element array of range values whose single element is the range `2..n-1`.  Thus, both `i` and `j` are range variables representing the range `2..n-1`.

Then, in the body of the loop, when trying to evaluate the expressions `i - 1..i + 1` and `j - 1..j + 1`, the compiler is complaining that the bounds of the ranges being constructed by the `..` operator are themselves ranges rather than some other supported type (like integers or enums).

To see this, [try the following code](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEAXQvaf4tCowyZZKJ4kWUmYDMopJ0entvf1y2cfW9sQnBTyugLFAT5MV4kzFxQgCMdZZKR71hiMJ4C1UfeSeJDqDToJU/bI3dy3EYbCitR8):

```
forall i in [2..n-1] do
  writeln(i, ": ", i.type:string);
```

which prints as its output:

```
2..99: range(int(64),bounded,false)
```

Or [this one](https://tio.run/##S85ILEjN@f8/OT8vLTNdoSyxSCFPwVbB0MDAmosLxCsC8jQM9fTyNPX0ILT1//8A):

```
config var n = 100;

var r = (1..n)..(1..n);
```

which prints a similar error to the one you're getting.

The one other thing going on here is that ranges support +/- operators taking integer values, which result in a translation of the range.  Thus, `i + 1`, where i is a unit-stride range, effectively becomes `i.low+1..i.high+1`.

Because of this subtlety, I've opened [this issue](https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/issues/21092), asking the question whether Chapel should require trailing commas in single-element array literals, much like it does for single-element tuples today.